# Where do I find a MemoryConsumer.java program to test consumption of memory?

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot

Where do I find a MemoryConsumer.java  program to test consumption of memory?   I know that such a thing already exists , as I see references via Google to such things.   For example, this Oracle site refers to "ConsumeHeap.java"  but I don't know where to find that source code.

[hotspot 1.6 options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/clopts-139448.html#gbzrr)

Does anyone know where to find or how to create such a thing?

Answer (score 2):

You could simply create a huge amount of object instances and keep them in scope.

```
ArrayList<SomeObject> listOfObjects = new ArrayList<SomeObject>;
for (int i = 0; i < aBigNumber; i++) {
  listOfObjects.add(new SomeObject());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've used this `ObjectSizer` class to good effect:

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=83

It works by creating huge amounts of object instances, as suggested by Tyler.

Answer (score 1):

That's really quite trivial:

```
public class ConsumeHeap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = new int[2000000000];
    }
}
```

That should result in an immediate OutOfMemoryError being thrown on all 32-Bit VMs. The following should provoke the exception for all contemporary VMs, as it would require 16 * 10^18 Bytes of memory:

```
public class ConsumeHeap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] a = new int[2000000000][2000000000];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general a operation is considered as extensive if this operation has a long runtime or a high memory consumption.
The total used / free memory of an program can be obtained in the program via java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime();

The runtime has several method which relates to the memory. The following coding example demonstrate its usage.

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PerformanceTest {
  private static final long MEGABYTE = 1024L * 1024L;

  public static long bytesToMegabytes(long bytes) {
    return bytes / MEGABYTE;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // I assume you will know how to create a object Person yourself...
    List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100000; i++) {
      list.add(new Person("Jim", "Knopf"));
    }
    // Get the Java runtime
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    // Run the garbage collector
    runtime.gc();
    // Calculate the used memory
    long memory = runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory();
    System.out.println("Used memory is bytes: " + memory);
    System.out.println("Used memory is megabytes: "
        + bytesToMegabytes(memory));
  }
}
```